# How to remember past searches for anonymous users

Tags: flask, session, cookies, session-cookies

My application doesn't have user accounts, the users anonymously interact with it.

I want to be able to remember what a user has searched for previously without attaching it to their account (as they don't have one). How would I go about doing this?

Is `cookies` the answer I am looking for? If so, can you point me in the right direction.

*Clarification: when the users clicks the search bar to search for something, I want to be able to display what that specific user has searched for in the past in a drop-down box.*

Answer (score 0):

you can use `localStorage` in this situation

There are code snippets which will help you (**preliminarily** add jQuery in you project for example in head of html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

). Just add it in your templates

```js
//selector by id - #selector, by class - .selector, by tag - selector

function getItemsFromLS(){
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('search'))
}

function addNewItemToLS(item){
  localStorage.setItem('search',JSON.stringify([...getItemsFromLS(), item]))
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  //if there are no storage create it
  if(!localStorage.getItem('search')){
    localStorage.setItem('search', JSON.stringify([]))
  }

  //click on the search button
  $('search-button-selector').click(function(){
     //get item form input
     let newItem = $('input-type-selector').val()
     addNewItemToLS(newItem)
  })
  
  //show items on focus of search bar
  $('input-type-selector').focus(function(){
    let searchItems = []
    $(this).change(function(){
    searchItems = getItemsFromLS().filter((item)=>item.includes($(this).val())) 

    $('list-of-search').empty()

searchItems.forEach((item)=>{
      $('list-of-search').append(`<span>${item}</span>`)
    })
  })
    })
})
```